# Is curly braces needed in initialization of an array of pointers in structure?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I have compiled a C code using Dev C++ and SPC5 Studio which has a structure with an array of pointers to another structure.

```
   typedef struct
    {
      uint16 Identifier_u16;
      void* const DataFncType;
    }ClassCfg_ts;

    typedef struct
    {
      uint32 Val_u32;
      ClassCfg_ts*  ClassRef_pu[2];
    }atrb_paramCfg_ts;
```

The initialisation is as given below

```
ClassCfg_ts ClassCfg1_s[] = {
{0,writeFucntion},//read write fucntion
{1,writeFucntion},//read write fucntion
{2,writeFucntion},//read write fucntion
};

ClassCfg_ts ClassCfg2_s[] = {
{0,writeFucntion},//read write fucntion
{1,writeFucntion},//read write fucntion
{2,writeFucntion},//read write fucntion
};

atrb_paramCfg_ts atrb_paramCfg_s[] =
{
{0,ClassCfg1_s},
{0,ClassCfg2_s},
};
```

where writeFunciton is defined. This initialization works perfectly whenDev C++ is used, whereas in SPC5 studio gives a warning for including curly braces and it disappears only if the initialisation is changed to

```
atrb_paramCfg_ts atrb_paramCfg_s[] =
{
{0,{ClassCfg1_s}},
{0,{ClassCfg2_s}},
};
```

Which among this is the correct initialisation?

Comment: You are aware that `void* const` can't be used to express a function pointer, yes?

Comment: it is working for me, I do a casting to the type of function pointer used before calling it. However that is not the question here, I have made different typedefs of the function pointers for better standards.

Comment: Just pointing out that casting from `void*` to a function pointer gives undefined behavior, and can cause weird bugs on some systems. Instead of `void*`, use `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @Lundin `uintptr_t` is likewise insufficient for a function pointer.  Re: C11 7.20.1.4

Comment: "Which among this is the correct initialisation?" --> None. A `void *` is not specified to be of sufficient width to properly store a _function pointer_.  Instead store in some function pointer, casting between function pointer type as needed. C11 §6.3.2.3 8

Comment: @chux Fair enough, but then use whatever flavour of integer that's more suitable. The point here is that conversions between integers and function pointers is well-defined. Conversions between object pointers and function pointers is not.

Comment: @Lundin Disagree about "conversions between integers and function pointers is well-defined".    A compliant C need not provide any integer type sufficient to properly store a function pointer.  "If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
the behavior is undefined."  §6.3.2.3 6

Comment: @chux It _is_ well-defined, if there's an integer type that is able to represent a function pointer. As it happens, this is the case for every real-world computer I have ever heard of - including oddball architectures with segmented memory.

Comment: @chux On such a futuristic computer, use `uint128_t`, available on your favourite futuristic compiler. On that same compiler, `uintptr_t` is also 128 bits from what I heard. In comparison, the leap from 32 to 64 bit wasn't done so much because someone needed 64 bit arithmetic, but rather because 64 bit address space was needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClassRef_p` is an array of pointers to `ClassCfg_ts`. You need to brace initialize arrays. `{ClassCfg2_s}` is correct way to initialize it in the above snippet.

Comment: Agree with your answer, but why is Dev C++ accepting it without braces? with braces, it gives error messages.

Comment: @ArunCheriyan; Check in the setting if you are compiling the program with C compiler or C++ compiler.

Comment: The Compiler is TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64bit